# Inserting a value has_and_belongs_to_many associated table on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have generate two table and its model and controllers using the scaffold  command on Rails

The two tables are User and Role

scaffold command create the two tables model and controllers.

### app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many   :roles
end
```

### app/models/role.rb

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Then I used the following command to generate the many-to-many relationship third table.

```
rails generate migration CreateJoinTableUserRole User Role
```

For this third table rails does not generate models or controllers. How do i add the values to this table? Do i need to create model for this table separately or do it another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate the migration:

```
rails g migration create_join_table :roles, :users
```

Then, you can simply save association like so:

```
@user.roles << @role
```

Where `@user` is `User` object and `@role` is `Role` object.

Note: Things that you should always keep in mind here is that join table names are arranged in alphabetical order, in this case ***roles*** should come before ***users***, Hence: `roles_users` will be the table that should be created to make HABTM work as per Rails convention.

Comment: In the Role table I have only two fields

Comment: id and role_name. How do i create the @role object and asssign it. Sorry. I'm new to rails..

Comment: `Role.create(role_name: 'admin')` then `Role.find(1)` where "1"(assuming that there were no entries before) is the id of the row in `roles` table.

Answer (score -1):

For this Third table, you dont need any controller  or model. It stores the record of `user` and `role`.
when you create a `role` for user in `UserController` or anywhere else like:

```
@user.roles << @role
```

Given you have two objects @user and @role of class User and Role respectively .

It will create a new row in that table containing `@user`'s id and `Roles`'s id and same for the opposite case i.e when you create a `user` for a Role.

```
@role.users << User.find(1)
```

or

```
@roles.users << @user
```

Rails guide on [HABTM](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference) association.

Comment: can you please give me the full command for adding the entry for the third table. 
my third table have only the entry  user_id and role_id

Comment: I already showed you some examples and a reference link. just do like that and it will fill that `user_id` and `role_id` itself. I can't give you actual code without seeing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is not going to work because HABTM is not going to save a `Role.new` object and hence it won't save it in `@user.roles`, vice-versa. Probably `Role.find(1)` would be a better example.

Comment: you are right, I was a little distracted. I will edit

Comment: Also, OP is creating a join table which is not according to the Rails convention, it is `CreateJoinTableUserRole` instead of `CreateJoinTableRolesUsers`. Hence, to address that answer should also explain to add a `join_table:` option in the association that OP is trying to create.